# How to hide items in RadioButtonList after selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void Bind_TimeSlots()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_GETAPPOINTMENTTIME", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@drid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hdfid.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@APPTDATE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtdate.Text;
    SqlDataReader drAppointmentTimings = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rbtTimeSlots.DataSource = drAppointmentTimings;
    rbtTimeSlots.Items.Clear();
    rbtTimeSlots.DataTextField = "TimeSlot";
    rbtTimeSlots.DataValueField = "id";
    rbtTimeSlots.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void btnAppointmentTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bind_TimeSlots();
}
```

Here I've RadioButtonList.... and Bind in a Button Click event

Now after selecting the item in RadiButtonList, The item has to hide for next selection

Comment: Do u want to hide selected radio item after button click?

Comment: yes.. the list is visible in modal popup

Comment: Check my answer.. inform me if not solved...

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the reason why you want to do this but :

**First Approach**

let's say `Rating` is the ID of the RadioButtonList

Yes, you can hide one by setting its `Enabled` property to false:

```
Rating.Items[0].Enabled = false;
Editing based on comment by OP.
```

To completely get rid of it you'll need to do this:

```
Rating.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

and then when you want it back you'll need to do this:

```
Rating.Items.Insert(0, "0");
```

**Second Approach**

Use CSS i.e

```
RadioButtonList.Items(1).CssClass.Add("visibility", "hidden")
```

Comment: Actually its an appointment List.... If person got the appointment then next person doesn't have that time in his availability List

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do select from text and also you can use FindByValue("val")

```
public void Bind_TimeSlots()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_GETAPPOINTMENTTIME", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@drid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hdfid.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@APPTDATE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtdate.Text;
        SqlDataReader drAppointmentTimings = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        rbtTimeSlots.DataSource = drAppointmentTimings;
        rbtTimeSlots.Items.Clear();
        rbtTimeSlots.DataTextField = "TimeSlot";
        rbtTimeSlots.DataValueField = "id";
        rbtTimeSlots.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }

    protected void btnAppointmentTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string selectedval = rbtTimeSlots.SelectedItem.Text; //if by value then SelectedValue.ToString()
        Bind_TimeSlots();
    if (rbtTimeSlots.Items.FindByText(selectedval) != null)  //if by value then rbtTimeSlots.Items.FindByValue(selectedval)()
           {              
               rbtTimeSlots.Items.FindByText(selectedval).Selected = true;  
               rbtTimeSlots.Items.FindByText(selectedval).Enabled = false;  
           }  
    }
```

Comment: @shrish--Good for him :)

Comment: i ve totally 98 TimeSlots

Comment: @SudharaniG No problem u can use FindByValue if your text will be same so u will get all things proper just use code which I have provided..